# How to properly use empty views on Android's ListView widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

After many days of search-and-try without success, I just cannot figure out how to properly use `ListView.setEmptyView` feature. Almost all examples I have found use a `ListActivity` which is not my case. I'm implementing a regular `Activity` with other widgets beyond the `ListView`, roughly described by the following picture:

> Picture of a Normal layout on the left, and the empty view placed at the bottom. http://picpaste.com/g3926-0UP1wBBB.png

I'm using the following code to set the empty view (this code fragment is written inside `onCreate` method):

```
mListView.setEmptyView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
        R.layout.emptyview_default,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1)));
```

The `emptyview_default` is a simple `TextView`:

```
<merge xmlns:android="...">
    <TextView ... />
</merge>
```

The "empty view" is always shown at the bottom of all other widgets, not inside the list (were the `ListView` view would normally appears, as shown in the picture above).

I have also tried to use the `ListView` itself (`mListView`) as the root `ViewGroup` for the inflate method, but the application crashes.

I'm expecting for advices or any directions that help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so instead of using `inflate(int, ViewGroup)` (which will return the root layout itself instead of the inflated View), use `inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)` like so:

```
LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(this);
ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
View empty = i.inflate(R.layout.emptyview_default, root, false);
mListView.setEmptyView(empty);
```

The problem is that the inflate method that takes an `int` and `ViewGroup` will attach the inflated `View` to the passed `ViewGroup`, and return that `ViewGroup`. If you use the extra parameter to pass `false`, the `ViewGroup` will only be used to generate `LayoutParams` for the inflated `View`, but will *not* add it to the `ViewGroup`. This will also cause `inflate()` to return the inflated `View`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it not worked. With the `merge` application crashes with `android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true`. Then I replaced the `<merge \>` with a `<LinearLayout \>` and the behavior remains the same: when the list is empty, the empty view is placed at the bottom.